# How to validate settings.xml in Service Fabric are being used?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Using settings.xml you can set various replicator/store settings (see: [this documentation link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-kvsactorstateprovider-configuration/)). But I can't find a way to validate if these settings are actually being picked up. For example we have been experimenting with the MaxVerPages setting by including a section in the settings.xml:

```
<Section Name="MyActorServiceLocalStoreConfig">
   <Parameter Name="MaxVerPages" Value="8192" />
</Section>
```

I'm running on a 1 node local dev cluster, version 2.2.207
I've searched the Service Fabric Explorer and I have examined the API (using the FabricClient) but I was unable to find a property that reflects MaxVerPages or any of these settings (BatchAcknowledgementInterval, MaxReplicationMessageSize, MaxPrimaryReplicationQueueSize, etc.) for that matter.

Can someone tell me how to get the currently used value for i.e. MaxVerPages?

Comment: @MichielOvereem I missread the question hence I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's under the Details tab for a particular application. Since the services settings get mapped to variables in the application manifest you'll see variable names based on that, not specially the variable names used in the services settings.xml

[image]